# Sculpture mode issue

Tags: modifiers

I'm having issues with sculpture mode. I draw objects for 2d animations and after a while I finished when I want to edit it in the sculpture mode I cant do it. I select the object I want to edit then entered the sculpture mode it shows the brushes and all but soon as I try to edit or something it doesn't work my layers are unlocked and a was able to edit it before but now it just don't work for me. maybe I pressed something wrong or... I don't know

Comment: Can you share your file? Pretty hard to quess without it

Comment: I dont now how but i actually get that sorted. Thank you anyway! :)